# ContentTools - What is the easiest way to add a div around a created table?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, content-tools

I try to make the tables created with ContentTools responsive by adding a `div` around a table and the following css.

```
style="overflow-x:auto;"
```

What is the easiest way to add the `div` around each created table by ContentTools? (http://getcontenttools.com/)

Comment: Can you use [inspect element](https://www.lifewire.com/get-inspect-element-tool-for-browser-756549) to find the generated html for the table, and include that in the question?

Comment: We (the team behind CT) are looking into exactly this behaviour ourselves right now. It's likely that we'll take the approach of using JS to apply the wrapping div tag on page load rather than insert div tags as part of the table element.